# Dynamically Generate Multiple GroupBoxes on Button Click in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, groupbox

I am working on a WPF app where I need to dynamically create GroupBoxes(which contains combobxes, sliders and togglebutton) based on Button Click. I have two xaml files in my View Folder. 'CodecView.xaml' and 'CodecWidgetView.xaml'.

**CodecView.XAML:**

```
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Name="GroupBoxScroll" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" >
            <Grid Name="NumberofCodecs" Style="{DynamicResource styleBackground}" />                  
        </ScrollViewer>            
    </Grid>

    <Button Content="Add Box" Name="AddBoxBtn" Command="{Binding AddGroupBoxCommand}" />
```

**CodecWidgetView.xaml:**

```
<GroupBox Header="{Binding GroupBoxHeader}" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,0,0" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ToggleButton Name="FrequencyBox" Content="Master" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="comboBox2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="80" />
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="80" />
            </Grid>
            s
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ToggleButton Name="OneSixBit" Content="16 Bit" Grid.Column="0" Height="25" Width="45" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
                <ToggleButton Name="ThreeTwoBit" Content="32 Bit" Grid.Column="3" Height="25" Width="45" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
                <ToggleButton Name="TwentyBit" Content="20 Bit" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" Width="45" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
                <ToggleButton Name="TwentyFourBit" Content="24 Bit" Grid.Column="2" Height="25" Width="45" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <Label Name="BitDelay" Content="Bit Delay" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,205,0" Height="25" Width="55" />
                <Slider Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="255.0" TickFrequency="1.0" Margin="95,0,0,0" Name="bitdelayslider" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="160" />
                <TextBox Name="BitDelayValue" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding ElementName=bitdelayslider,Path=Value}" Width="40" Height="20" Margin="0,0,110,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                <Label Name="DBGain" Content="DB Gain" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,205,0" Height="25" Width="55" />
                <TextBox Name="DBGainValue" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding ElementName=dbgainslider,Path=Value}" Width="40" Height="20" Margin="0,0,110,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Slider Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="59.5" TickFrequency="0.5" Margin="95,0,0,0" Name="dbgainslider" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="160" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
```

**CodecViewModel:** Is a view model of CodecView.xaml

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Event for Refresh Button
    /// </summary>
    private ICommand mAddGroupBoxCommand;
    public ICommand AddGroupBoxCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mAddGroupBoxCommand == null)
                mAddGroupBoxCommand = new DelegateCommand(new Action(mAddGroupBoxCommandExecuted), new Func<bool>(mAddGroupBoxCommandCanExecute));

            return mAddGroupBoxCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            mAddGroupBoxCommand = value;
        }
    }

    public bool mAddGroupBoxCommandCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void mAddGroupBoxCommandExecuted()
    {
        //Here It should display the groupbox 4 times
    }
```

**ModelClass:**

```
private string GroupBoxHeaderName;
    public string GroupBoxHeader
    {
        get
        {
            return GroupBoxHeaderName;
        }

        set
        {
            GroupBoxHeaderName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupBoxHeader");
        }
    }
```

Thus I want to add this Groupbox present in `CodecWidgetView.xaml` to my grid`(NumberofCodecs)` in `CodecView.xaml` on startup. And when I click the `AddBoxButton` it should dynamically generate the groupbox 4 times and display it :)

Now this is tricky, each Groupbox Header must display different names in every dynamically generated groupbox. Lets say on startup, 2 groupboxes are already displayed with `Groupbox Header = "Location 1"` and `GroupBox Header = "Location 2"`. On `AddgroupBox button` click I want to have 4 groupboxes with Header as `Groupbox Header = "Location 3" Groupbox Header = "Location 4" Groupbox Header = "Location 5" Groupbox Header = "Location 6"`.

Is it possible? :)

Comment: yes.. its possible and simple too.. if you are a newbee to WPF you have to learn using ItemsControl and Item template...

Comment: @bathineni: Well I have spent sometime on WPF and never came across this scenario. I would appreciate if you can help me solve this problem :)

Comment: sure will help you... I am trying to build a sample...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following code i am taking a itemscontrol in "CodecView.xaml" and for that itemscontrol ItemTemplate is your "CodecWidgetView.Xaml" and added description to that datatemplate. i have created another class CodecWidgetViewModel.cs which will be view model for "CodecWidgetView" view.

In the constructor of "CodecViewModel" i am creating instance for "CodecWidgetViewModel" and adding them to observable collection which is source of ItemsControl in the "CodecView"..

so at this point it will generate 2 CodecWidgetViews.. on button click i am adding 4 more instances so it will generate 4 CodecWidgetViews.. You can modify the code in the "mAddGroupBoxCommandExecuted" method as per your requirement..

on Button click

**CodecView.XAML**

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CWDataTemplate">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                <local:CodecWidgetView/>
                    </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <Grid>
                <ScrollViewer Name="GroupBoxScroll" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" >
                    <Grid Name="NumberofCodecs" Style="{DynamicResource styleBackground}" >
                        <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CWDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding CodecWidgets}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>

            <Button Content="Add Box" Name="AddBoxBtn" Command="{Binding AddGroupBoxCommand}" Click="AddBoxBtn_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  />
        </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**CodecViewModel.cs**

**Create a property like this**

```
  public ObservableCollection<CodecWidgetViewModel> CodecWidgets { get; set; }
```

**And add following code to your CodecViewModel constructor**

```
 CodecWidgets = new ObservableCollection<CodecWidgetViewModel>();
            CodecWidgets.Add(new CodecWidgetViewModel { Description = "Location 1"});
            CodecWidgets.Add(new CodecWidgetViewModel { Description = "Location 2" });
```

**To Add widgets**

```
public void mAddGroupBoxCommandExecuted()
    {
         CodecWidgets.Add(new CodecWidgetViewModel { Description = "Location 3" });
            CodecWidgets.Add(new CodecWidgetViewModel { Description = "Location 4" });
            CodecWidgets.Add(new CodecWidgetViewModel { Description = "Location 5" });
            CodecWidgets.Add(new CodecWidgetViewModel { Description = "Location 6" });
    }
```

**Create following class**
**CodecWidgetViewModel.cs**

```
public class CodecWidgetViewModel 
    {
        private string _description;
        public string Description {

            get { return _description; }
            set {
                _description = value;                   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Amazing :) Works without any issues :) just added a clear() to clear previous items. Thanks :)

Comment: Don't you think having a list is a good approach which will contain all the descriptions i.e. loc 1, loc 2 and so on. And we use it accordingly?

Comment: @StonedJesus we can use List.. i have used ObservableCollection because it will take care of notifying changes.. you can use list but then you have to raise property changed event after adding or removing widgets... or else you have to use CollectionViewSource

Comment: Well you are right. What I actually meant to say is to have a List<CodecWidgetViewModel> which will have all the descriptions from loc 1 to loc 8. And On button click we just display them by extracting from list. Basically rather than using `.add()` everywhere, y cant we just have one `.add()` which adds the description from the list :)